# JavaFX 8: Property bindings for custom objects

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a custom object hold by a `ObjectProperty` instance which should be bound to the `StringProperty` of a `javafx.scene.text.Text`.

If I do the obvious thing and use `text.textProperty().bind(..);` the object property gets bound and the `Text` actually displays content (I believe the result of `toString`).

But I do need to modify the `String` which is actually displayd in `text`.

Where can I modify what value is actually provided to the binding?

== **EDIT** ==

Following the first anwer I created this simple test application:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class BindingsTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final ObjectProperty<Foo> foo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        foo.set(Foo.FOO);

        final StringProperty textProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
        textProperty.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> foo.get().name().toLowerCase()));

        System.out.println(textProperty.get());

        foo.set(Foo.BAR);

        System.out.println(textProperty.get());

    }

    private enum Foo {
        FOO, BAR
    }
}
```

Both outputs are 'foo' whereas I expected the second one to be 'bar'. So after all probably `Bindings.createStringBinding(..)` is not what I am looking for?

Comment: Why don't you try it the way it is done in the answer??? I.e. specify `foo` as the second argument to `createStringBinding()`?

Comment: @James_D Oh I not even saw that - this Lambda things still confusing me; I thought I reproduced the solution correctly and that's why I posted it here :-)

Comment: You did not specify `foo` as its dependency. `Bindings.createStringBinding()` needs to observe for changes in `foo` in order to know when to invalidate itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`Bindings.createStringBinding()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createStringBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-).

```
final ObjectProperty<CustomObject> objProperty;
text.textProperty.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    final CustomObject value = objProperty.getValue();
    return value != null ? value.toString().toUpperCase() : "";
}, objProperty));
```

Comment: I believe that is not what I am looking for; I modified my question.